# Type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {ServersService} from "../servers.service";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

interface Server {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  status: string
}

@Injectable()
export class ServerResolverService implements Resolve<Server> {
  constructor(private serverService: ServersService) {
  }
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Server> | Promise<Server> | Server {
    let id = +route.params['id'] | 1;
    let server = this.serverService.getServer(id);
    return server; // error here in Angular 13
  }
}
```

The code looks correct but WebStorm is spitting this error

**error TS2322: Type '{ id: number; name: string; status: string; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Server | Observable | Promise'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Server | Observable | Promise'.**

The ServerService file looks like

```
export class ServersService {
  private servers = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Productionserver',
      status: 'online'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Testserver',
      status: 'offline'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Devserver',
      status: 'offline'
    }
  ];

  getServers() {
    return this.servers;
  }

  getServer(id: number) {
    const server = this.servers.find(
      (s) => {
        return s.id === id;
      }
    );
    return server;
  }

  updateServer(id: number, serverInfo: { name: string, status: string }) {
    const server = this.servers.find(
      (s) => {
        return s.id === id;
      }
    );
    if (server) {
      server.name = serverInfo.name;
      server.status = serverInfo.status;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ServerService`, I cant see that the type `Server` is defined. If it is not, please define the type there and assign it to your array as follows, then simply import the interface in your resolver:

```js
export interface Server {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  status: string
}


export class ServersService {
  private servers: Server[] = [ //here
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Productionserver',
      status: 'online'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Testserver',
      status: 'offline'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Devserver',
      status: 'offline'
    }
  ];

  getServers() {
    return this.servers;
  }

  getServer(id: number) {
    const server = this.servers.find(
      (s) => {
        return s.id === id;
      }
    );
    return server;
  }

  updateServer(id: number, serverInfo: { name: string, status: string }) {
    const server = this.servers.find(
      (s) => {
        return s.id === id;
      }
    );
    if (server) {
      server.name = serverInfo.name;
      server.status = serverInfo.status;
    }
  }
}
```

Is it certain that `getServer` always returns a server? or the id can also result into `undefined`? If the id is always valid, please try defining the return type for your `getServer` method in `ServerService`:

```js
getServer(id: number): Server {
    const server = this.servers.find(
      (s) => {
        return s.id === id;
      }
    );
    return server;
  }
```

Also, define the type for your variable here:

```js
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Server> | Promise<Server> | Server {
    let id = +route.params['id'] | 1;
    let server: Server = this.serverService.getServer(id);  // here
    return server; // error here in Angular 13
  }
```

Perhaps this removes the error. In short, as I see, `Server` interface is only defined in your resolver service, but your servers array in `ServerService` is not of type `Server[]`.

Answer (score 0):

`ServersService.getServer`'s return type includes `undefined`, because it just returns the result of `find` which can be `undefined`. E.g. what do you expect to be returned if you call `this.serverService.getServer(5)`?

So you can handle this in two ways:

1. Make sure `getServer` never returns `undefined` (and specifying the return type you want explicitly is a good idea).
2. Handle the `undefined` case inside `resolve`.